# register system with php/mysql: can 't find user

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, phpmyadmin

i am new in php/mysql and sorry if my question is silly. I am trying to make a register/login/logout system with php and mysql. My skills are not good and i am not a programmer, so i tried to change a script that i found on the web.  It contains  files, index.php, activate php. login.php, logout.php, register.php.

It worked great when I tried the example given, but ***i changed the code quite a bit because I wanted the user to add more values in register like first name, last name etc and not just username, password and email.*** So I changed the code and added more columns on the mysql database. Now it won t work, it says that can 't find user when i try to activate and i also can 't log in.

**index.php:** is a very simple file that has an html form and asks unknown user if he wants to login or register and also starts a session

**logout.php:** simply unsets session

**login.php:**

```
 <?php session_start(); ?>
<html>
<body>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST["user"])){
        $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
        if (!$con)
          {
          die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
          }

        mysql_select_db("myapp", $con);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user` LIKE '". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["user"])
        ."' AND ".
            "`pass` LIKE MD5('". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["pass"])
        ."') AND ".
            "`active` = 'DONE'";

        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        $found = 0;
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            if ($row[1]==$_POST["user"]) {
                $found = 1;
            }
        }

        if ($found) {
        $_SESSION["USER"] = $_POST["user"];
        ?>Thank you for logging in<?
        }
        else {
        ?>User/Pass is wrong!<?
        }

        mysql_close($con);
    }
    else {
    ?>

        Please log-in:<br/>
        <form action="login.php" method="POST">
            User: <input type="text" name="user"><br />
            Pass: <input type="password" name="pass"><br />
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>

    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

**register.php:**

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<html>
<body>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["user"])){
        $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
        if (!$con)
          {
          die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
          }

        mysql_select_db("myapp", $con);

        $random = rand();

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `myapp`.`users` (`id`, `user`, `pass`, `active`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `mail`) ".
        " VALUES (NULL, '". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["user"])
        ."', MD5('".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["pass"])
        ."'), '".mysql_real_escape_string($random)
        ."'), '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["firstname"])
        ."'), '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["lastname"])
        ."')'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["mail"])
        ."');";

        mysql_query($sql);

        mysql_close($con);

        $message = "Please put this url http://localhost/mypage/activate.php?active=" . $random . " in your browser to activate your account.";
        @mail($_POST["mail"], 'Thank you for registering', $message);

        ?>Thank you <?php echo $_POST["user"]; ?> we send you a confirmation e-mail in <?php echo $_POST["mail"]; ?><?php

        echo $message;
    }
    else {
        ?>
        Please register:<br/>
        <form action="register.php" method="POST">
            User: <input type="text" name="user"><br />
            Pass: <input type="password" name="pass"><br />
            firstname:<input type="text" name="firstname"><br />
            lastname:<input type="text" name="lastname"><br />
            mail: <input type="text" name="mail"><br />

            <input type="submit" />
        </form>

        <?php
    }
?>
```

***activate.php:***

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<html>
<body>
        <?php
    if(isset($_GET["active"])){
        $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
        if (!$con)
          {
          die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
          }

        mysql_select_db("myapp", $con);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `active` LIKE '".      
mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["active"])."'";

        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        $found = 0;
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $found = 1;
        }

        if ($found) {

        $sql = "UPDATE `users` SET `active` ='DONE'";

        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        ?>Thank you for activating<?
        }
        else {
        ?>Can't find user!<?
        }

        mysql_close($con);
    }
    else {
    ?>Invalid activation<?php
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

any help would be welcome, thank you and sorry for the long post!! ^_^

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ***register.php***, you have an error in the SQL syntax, you have too many closed parentheses.
Replace this part like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `myapp`.`users` (`id`, `user`, `pass`, `active`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `mail`) VALUES 
   (NULL,". 
   "'". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["user"])."',".
   "MD5('".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["pass"])."'),".
   "'".mysql_real_escape_string($random)."',".
   "'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["firstname"])."',".
   "'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["lastname"])."',".
   "'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["mail"])."');";
```